# Issues kicking off Attunity Replication job - Task Server

Tags: replication, attunity

My org is just beginning to work on replacing our existing DWH platform with Snowflake/Attunity/WhereScape and some (for now) unnamed Data Vis. tool, but we're running into a weird error and I'm hoping someone has seen the same thing and can maybe point me in the right direction.

We have 2 replication jobs, one from an Oracle source and one from a SQL Server source, and they are both failing and throwing the error "Task Server Initialization Failed", without churning any useful logs.

We had the initial thought that it was a setup issue and that I had done something wrong in setting up the Data Lake or the source endpoint, but we were able to successfully replicate with the same account on another DB with me at the helm, so...i don't think it's me.

I'm going to have a DBA work with me to go line-by-line and verify that the permission match the Attunity user guide, but does anyone out there have any tips or know where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have stumbled upon this post in an attempt to solve this problem, we are currently working with Attunity to find the source of this problem, but it seems to be related to a caching issue. 
Exporting the task to JSON, renaming it, and importing it with a new name resolves the issue, and is a (semi) acceptable workaround.